# Guessing the function, integration

Tags: integration

While solving an electrostatics problem by making various approximations, I finally came up with these two condition for the charge density as a function of $x$:

$\int_{0}^{R}{\sigma (x) x dx} =0$

(That is to say, total charge on the disk is 0)

$\int_{0}^{r} {  \sigma (x) x dx  }= (\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 L^3}) r$

With $r \leq R$.  Let $k$  be the quantity in parenthesis. $R,k$ are some constants. How can I find $\sigma(x)$, in terms of $x,k,R$?

Comment: Is $\sigma(x)$ continuous? I seem to be getting a contradictory result.

Comment: @ElieLouis   Yes, $\sigma (x)$ should be continuous. Have you considered that it can be negative in some points and positive in others?

Comment: Using $x$ as bounds and integration dummy makes things confusing. Do you mind changing the integration dummy please?

Comment: Edited, hope it's more understandable

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating your second equation wrt $x$
$$
\sigma(x) x = k
$$
$$
\sigma(x) = \frac{k} {x} 
$$
Your first equation then yields
$$
\int_0^R k dx = 0
$$
$$
Rk = 0
$$
Thus either $k=0$ or $R=0$.

Comment: This is what I got. So the result is contradictory, since he wants $\sigma(x)$ in terms of arbitrary $k$ and $R$.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work for arbitrary $k$ and $R$, I'm wondering if the right hand side of his first equation should be $q$ from the small amount of context given.